# Node js supertest is async?

Tags: node.js, supertest, should.js

I want to write some tests for some routes and I want to do something like this:

```
var should = require('should');
var app = require('../../app');
var request = require('supertest');

describe('Create and check that the create was successfull', function() {
    var user_id = '';
  it('should add a new case and return a JSON array', function(done) {
    var newUser = {nume : 'Test', prenume: 'test', varsta : 23};
    request(app)
      .post('/api/new_user')
      .send(newUser)
      .expect(201)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.body.should.be.instanceOf(Array);
        res.body.should.have.property('_id');
        user_id = res.body._id;
        done();
      });
  });

  it('should return the new user ', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/api/new_user/' + user_id)
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.body.should.be.instanceOf(Object);
        res.body._id.should.be.exactly(user_id);
        done();
      });
  });

});
```

I am not sure if the two it statements are executed one after the other or each one is done async and when I get to the second it the first one is not executed so it will fail because the insert was not done in the server. 
Should I use async.series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example supertest is only responsible for the chain from `request(app)` down, so it's actually the provider of the `describe()` and `it()` calls that determines the order, or lack thereof, in which your tests are executed, which I guess is mocha, right?

If so, Mocha will run your testcases in order (as in, the second one will be called once the first one has finished).

Answer (score 0):

Supertest **request** can't persist session therefore your second test case seems failing. Basically the second case running as it is not aware at all about the first case.

You can persist your session with **request.agent**.

Below is a quick example:

```
var should = require('should');
var app = require('../../app');
var request = require('supertest');

describe('Create and check that the create was successfull', function() {
  var session;

  var new_user = {name:'Test',presume:'test',vast:'23'};
  var user_id;

  before (function(done){

  session = request.agent(app);

  session
     .post('/api/new_user')
     .send('new_user')
     .expect(201)
     .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
     .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.body.should.be.instanceOf(Array);
        res.body.should.have.property('_id');
        user_id = res.body._id;
        done();
     });

  });

  it('should return the new user ', function(done){

    session
      .get('/api/new_user/' + user_id)
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.body.should.be.instanceOf(Object);
        res.body._id.should.be.exactly(user_id);
        done();
      });

  });

  ...

});
```